# How to trigger event on TakeProfit

Tags: mql4

I am working on this problem for several weeks now and I just can't find a proper way to solve it. I am looking for help.

**I want the following to happen:**

1. Place 2 orders, n and n+1. n has a TP & SL level, n+1 has only SL level. SL levels are the same for both orders.
2. If SL is hit, fine. Both orders are terminated.
3. If TP on order n is hit, modify order n+1 to have its SL moved to the price where order n hit TP.
4. After that I want to execute trailing stop loss and I have already programmed that successfully.

How is this done? I tried with magic numbers, iterating over HistoryDealsTotal, HistoryOrdersTotal and a few more approaches but I just never get to the point where I am able to track an order inbetween many open orders and check if it just hit TP, then modify the other order that was initially created right after the first order.

I would appreciate any help towards a solution, thanks!

Comment: When you place your orders, record the ticket numbers. Track these until one disappears from the live orders, then check in order history if it was in profit or not when it closed. If it was in profit get the take profit level and use this on the remaining live order.

Comment: This is an approach I have considered  but the downside to this is the ticket number changes when a new order  has been sent. Say I'm in EU and the ticket number is 1 when I send another other the ticket number  will no longer be 1. Unless I'll have to save the numbers in an array or object?

Comment: The ticket number of an existing order will not change unless you partially close the trade, in which case usually a new ticket number is generated for the remainder of the trade that remains live. In your scenario the ticket number will not change and my approach should work as I have used it numerous times myself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint man this was helpful,  I was able to solve the problem  though  I didn't  use order tickets  I use the order open time  and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I came up with a solution to the problem above.
here is a breakdown.

I looped through my order history and recorded the following;

- OrderOpenTime();
- OrderSymbol();
- OrderType();
- OrderLots();

**Note: the data you record is up to you.**

I then loop through the OrdersTotal with the data I have got for possible matches and then modify the match.

**Hence;**

```js
datetime OrderDateTime=0; // variable to store the OrderOpenTime
   string orderSymbol=""; 
   int orderType=0 ;
   double orderLot=0.0;
   int TotalHistoryOrders = OrdersHistoryTotal(),TotalOrders=OrdersTotal();

   for(int h = TotalHistoryOrders - 1; h >= 0; h--)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(h, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY))  // checking through orderHistory 
        {
         if(OrderSymbol() == _Symbol)
           {
            if(OrderType() == OP_SELL || OrderType() == OP_BUY)
              {
               if(OrderProfit() >= 0) // checking if the closed trade was in profit 
                 {
                  //saving the needed data from the history data
                  OrderDateTime = OrderOpenTime();
                  orderSymbol = OrderSymbol();
                  orderType = OrderType();
                  orderLot = OrderLots();
                 }
               for(int i = TotalOrders - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                 {
                    //checking opened trades for a possible match
                  if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES))
                     if(OrderOpenTime() == OrderDateTime|| OrderOpenTime() == OrderDateTime+1) // +1 just incase the second order opens a second later 
                       {
                        if(OrderSymbol() == orderSymbol)
                          {
                           if(OrderType() == orderType)
                             {
                              if(OrderLots() == orderLot)
                                {

                                 // CHEKING IF STOP LOSS IS BELOW ONBAR_STOPLOSS
                                 if(OrderStopLoss() < Onbar_stoploss(OP_BUY)) // Onbar_stoploss is my stoploss function for Buy orders 
                                   {
                                    double stop_loss = Onbar_stoploss(OP_BUY); // setting the stoploss

                                    //MODIFYING STOP LOSS
                                    bool ORDER_MORDIFY1 = OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(), stop_loss, OrderTakeProfit(),0,clrNONE);

                                   }
                                 else
                                    if(OrderStopLoss() > Onbar_stoploss(OP_SELL))// Onbar_stoploss is my stoploss function  for sell orders
                                      {
                                       double stop_loss = Onbar_stoploss(OP_SELL); // setting the stoploss

                                       //MODIFYING STOP LOSS
                                       bool ORDER_MORDIFY1 = OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(), stop_loss, OrderTakeProfit(),0,clrNONE);

                                      }
                                }
                             }
                          }
                       }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

I hope this helps.